# convert following string into array using explode()

Tags: php

HI,
I have a string:

> NEW ALPINESTAR​S SMX PLUS WHITE
>   MOTORCYCLE BOOTS! 44/9.5$349.95 Time
>   Left 1h 2m NEW AGV BLADE FLAT MATTE
>   WHITE LARGE/LG HELMET$75.53Time Left
>   1h 2m

I want result in array like this:

> Productname
>   Price     time NEW ALPINESTAR​S SMX
>   PLUS WHITE MOTORCYCLE BOOTS! 44/9.5 
>   $349.95  Time Left 1h 2m

Comment: Please add some PHP code to your example to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
explode("Time Left 1h 2m", "NEW ALPINESTAR​S SMX PLUS WHITE MOTORCYCLE BOOTS! 44/9.5$349.95 Time Left 1h 2m NEW AGV BLADE FLAT MATTE WHITE LARGE/LG HELMET$75.53Time Left 1h 2m");
```